# Angular selected for multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on this fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/qWzTb/1706/)

this is my controller

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    { label: 'one', value: 'a' },
    { label: 'two', value: 'b' },
    { label: 'three', value: 'c' },
    { label: 'four', value: 'd' }
  ];

  $scope.selected = [{ 'sel': 'a' },{ 'sel': 'b' },{ 'sel': 'c' } ] ;


});
```

the `$scope.options` is the option for my select dom and the `$scope.selected` is the selected item in my select dom

this is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <div ng-repeat="data in selected">
            <select ng-model="data.sel"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
            </select>
            selected must be : {{data.sel}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

what I had is this

[image]

what I need is on first load the selected must be selected like this

[image]

could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ngInit for default:

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <div ng-repeat="data in selected">
            <select ng-model="data.sel"
            ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options" ng-init="data.sel = data.sel || options[$index].value">
        </select>
            selected must be : {{data.sel}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/qWzTb/1714/)

Comment: hi I try to change the selected object to  $scope.selected = [{ 'sel': 'a' },{ 'sel': 'a' },{ 'sel': 'a' } ] ; it seem not working could you try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/qWzTb/1713/

Comment: Did you try above answer in comment?

Comment: The original fiddle in the answer has also been updated

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-init` to select the `ng-model` value by their `$index`:

```
<select ng-model="data.sel" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" ng-init="data.sel = options[$index]"></select>
```

Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/1711/).

Comment: hi I try to change the selected object to  $scope.selected = [{ 'sel': 'a' },{ 'sel': 'a' },{ 'sel': 'a' } ] ; it seem not working could you try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/qWzTb/1713/

Comment: I don't get what your are trying to do.

Comment: the $scope.selected must be the selected value of select dom sir. since the ng-selected listen to index but $scope.selected returns value not index.